# Generating a non-convex polyhedron from a list of vertex coordinates

Tags: list-manipulation, computational-geometry

I want to include a figure in a paper I am writing on Combinatorial Geometry which features a non-convex polyhedron given by the following vertices,

EDIT: I was unaware that Mathematica could convert coordinates from spherical to Cartesian, so I will post the correct spherical coordinates as follows:

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, Pi/3, 0}, {1, Pi/3, ArcCos[1/3]},
 {1, Pi/3, 2 ArcCos[1/3]}, {1, Pi/3, 3 ArcCos[1/3]},
 {1, Pi/3, 4 ArcCos[1/3]}, {1, (2 Pi)/3, (ArcCos[1/3])/2},
 {1, (2 Pi)/3, (3 ArcCos[1/3])/2}, {1, (2 Pi)/3, (5 ArcCos[1/3])/2},
 {1, (2 Pi)/3, (7 ArcCos[1/3])/2}, {1, (2 Pi)/3, (9 ArcCos[1/3])/2}, {1, Pi, 0}}
```

Does anyone know how I can generate such a figure using Mathematica? I assume I will need to also somehow define which vertices are connected by an edge with a list, but I am unsure how I would do that as well. I have tried using the "Computational Geometry Package", and have been reading through the tutorial for about an hour, but I have no idea what a "vertex adjacency list" is or how I could make this work in 3-dimensions; the package tutorial seems to only comment on triangulations in the plane, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I will attempt to describe this non-convex polyhedron and include pictures and a figure.
[image: Real image]
[image: figure]
I will quote from my paper:

> The inspiration for constructing a simplicial 3-complex $\mathcal{K}$ for which 12 tetrahedra touch at a vertex comes from the configuration of 4 tetrahedra sharing an edge; see Figure 3. Let $v_{0}=(0,0,0)$ be the origin and connect the two vertices $v_{1}=(1,0,0)$ and $v_{12} = (-1,0,0)$ to $v_{0}$ by an edge. Label these edges as $e(v_{0}v_{1})$ and $e(v_{0}v_{12})$ and notice that their union forms a straight line of length 2 in $\mathbb{E}^3$. Around each of these edges we arrange four tetrahedra as in Figure 3, and we rotate the cluster of four tetrahedra sharing edge $e(v_{0}v_{12})$ by $\pi/6$ in order to ensure that an extra four tetrahedra will fit in between the two clusters of 4 tetrahedra (explained in more detail later). Considering the vertices of these tetrahedra, we obtain a point set $P$ (with $|P|=12$) where the minimum distance which can occur any of the points is of unit length.

Figure 3: in the context of my paper, this figure shows that at most 4 tetrahedra can share an edge with conditions I impose. If you imagine one of the tetrahedra removed so that there is a bigger space, these are the "clusters of 4 tetrahedra" I described above.
[image: figure 3]

---

(The bonus question was solved, thank you Mr. Wizard.)

BONUS: If anyone knows how to check with Mathematica if all of the points are at least a distance of 1 away from each other that would be very helpful.

Comment: For the bonus question: `Map[# >= 1 &, Outer[EuclideanDistance, N[pts, 20], N[pts, 20], 1], {2}]` has a good amount of off-diagonal `False` entries...

Comment: @J.M. doesn't `Outer` test many duplicates that way?

Comment: @J.M. I'm sorry I am not a Mathematica expert, I don't know what your answer means.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, yes, but at least the layout of the output is somewhat understandable (the first point's distance from the second point is greater than equal to 1, etc.)

Comment: Sam, what I did was to treat your list of points as a vector and construct the outer product of those two vectors, but I replaced multiplication with the Euclidean distance of two points. The outermost `Map[]` just checks your criterion.

Comment: I'm confused; are they spherical or cylindrical? What convention for spherical coordinates are you using? For instance, I'm used to $(r,\theta,\varphi)$ where $\theta$ is longitude and $\varphi$ is co-latitude...

Comment: I'm going according to what Mathematica states: "In the spherical coordinate system Spherical[r,theta,phi], the coordinate r gives the distance of the point from the origin, the coordinate \[Theta] gives the angle measured from the positive z axis, and the coordinate \[Phi] gives the angle measured in the x-y plane from the positive x axis, counterclockwise as viewed from the positive z axis. "

Comment: I now know why I don't play D&D anymore ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a starting point, you could generate an initial tetrahedralization of your points by using the `` TetGenLink` `` package:

```
pts = FullSimplify[TrigExpand[(#1 Append[Sin[#2]Through[{Cos, Sin}[#3]], Cos[#2]])]] & @@@
         {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, Pi/3, 0}, {1, Pi/3, ArcCos[1/3]},
          {1, Pi/3, 2 ArcCos[1/3]}, {1, Pi/3, 3 ArcCos[1/3]},
          {1, Pi/3, 4 ArcCos[1/3]}, {1, (2 Pi)/3, (ArcCos[1/3])/2},
          {1, (2 Pi)/3, (3 ArcCos[1/3])/2}, {1, (2 Pi)/3, (5 ArcCos[1/3])/2},
          {1, (2 Pi)/3, (7 ArcCos[1/3])/2}, {1, (2 Pi)/3, (9 ArcCos[1/3])/2}, {1, Pi, 0}};

Needs["TetGenLink`"]

{tpts, tets} = TetGenDelaunay[pts];

TetrahedraWireframe[i_] := Line[Flatten[i[[All, #]] & /@
                                {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}, 1]]

Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[tpts, TetrahedraWireframe[tets]]]
```

[image: Delaunay tetrahedralization of Sam's points]

Here's a version with labeled points, for guidance:

```
Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[tpts, TetrahedraWireframe[tets]], 
            MapIndexed[Style[Text[First[#2], #1, {-1, -1}], Red, 18] &, pts]}]
```

[image: labeled polyhedron]

Now, all that's needed is a criterion for knowing which lines should be retained, or a way to indicate connectivity ("point 1 is joined to points 7, 6, and 5; ...")...

---

OP managed to reckon out a patch list from the data given above:

```
patches = {{1, 2, 7}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 8}, {4, 5, 2}, {2, 5, 6}, {2, 6, 7},
           {1, 2, 3}, {7, 11, 12}, {6, 11, 7}, {8, 9, 4}, {13, 9, 8},
           {13, 10, 9}, {13, 11, 10}, {13, 12, 11}, {13, 1, 8}, {12, 1, 13},
           {11, 1, 10}, {10, 9, 1}, {9, 1, 4}, {7, 1, 12}, {6, 1, 11},
           {5, 4, 1}, {3, 1, 8}, {5, 6, 1}};
```

`GraphicsComplex[]` is of course what one should now use these days for reconstructing a polyhedron from points and patches. For reference, here's what was once done in old versions of *Mathematica*:

```
Graphics3D[Polygon[Part[pts, #] & /@ patches]]
```

[image: Sam's polyhedron]

---

If one had a list of edges as opposed to a list of patches:

```
edges = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 1 -> 6, 1 -> 7, 1 -> 8, 1 -> 9,
         1 -> 10, 1 -> 11, 1 -> 12, 1 -> 13, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6,
         2 -> 7, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 5, 4 -> 8, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7,
         6 -> 11, 7 -> 11, 7 -> 12, 8 -> 9, 8 -> 13, 9 -> 10, 9 -> 13,
         10 -> 11, 10 -> 13, 11 -> 12, 11 -> 13, 12 -> 13};
```

then one could use `GraphPlot3D[]` to visualize a wireframe of the polyhedron:

```
GraphicsRow[{
    GraphPlot3D[edges, Method -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"], 
    GraphPlot3D[edges, VertexCoordinateRules -> MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &, pts]]}]
```

[image: GraphPlot3D[] results]

Here, the picture on the right used the explicit coordinates given by the OP, while the picture on the left used a graph embedding method to choose "nice" (for the internal algorithm, that is) coordinates.

Comment: I have a physical model of this polyhedron, and I in fact constructed it for a particular purpose so I do know by looking at that picture you just uploaded exactly which edges should not be present.

Comment: Okay. Could you maybe include a picture of your physical model in your question for reference? :)

Comment: I edited my response and also just realized that I made a mistake converting some of the coordinates from spherical to cartesian, so I will re-upload the correct coordinate data in one moment. Thank you for all of the help!

Comment: If need be, you could post the original spherical coordinates, and we can then use *Mathematica* to do the conversion for you...

Comment: I have posted the spherical coordinates to the problem.

Comment: just about ready to accept the answer, but any idea how I would be able to create that criterion for which lines should be retained? I know what they are off the top of my head, but how I would I input that into Mathematica?

Comment: Okay, I was able to figure out all of my programs by looking through more tutorials. Thank you so so much for your invaluable help!

Comment: @Sam, "I know what they are off the top of my head" - could you maybe edit your post to include these? That might make this an even better answer...

Comment: The figure I generated from the code in my answer ended up in a paper I wrote: http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5756 if you are interested! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks good @Sam; thanks for linking to it! It might be best if you edit your original post to include that arXiv link instead, so that it's more prominently seen than here in the comments.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding your BONUS, you can get the minimum distance between all pairs of points like this:

```
list = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1/2, 0, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1/6, Sqrt[2]/3, Sqrt[3]/ 2}, {-(7/18), (2 Sqrt[2])/9, Sqrt[3]/ 2}, {-(23/54), -((5 Sqrt[2])/27), Sqrt[3]/2}, {17/ 162, -((28 Sqrt[2])/81), Sqrt[3]/2}, {Sqrt[3]/4, 1/ 4, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {(3 - 2 Sqrt[6])/(12 Sqrt[3]), ( 6 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3])/( 12 Sqrt[3]), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {(-63 - 12 Sqrt[6])/(108 Sqrt[3]), 1/36 (-7 + 4 Sqrt[6]), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1/ 108 (10 Sqrt[2] - 23 Sqrt[3]), 1/108 (-23 - 10 Sqrt[6]), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1/ 324 (56 Sqrt[2] + 17 Sqrt[3]), 1/324 (17 - 56 Sqrt[6]), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {0, 0, -1}};

EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[N @ list, {2}] // Min
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I am getting an error message when I attempt to try and compute that. Could you share a quick explanation for what "EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[list,{2}] // Min" means?

Comment: Okay, I believe you edited your answer so that I would input:
"EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[N@list, {2}] // Min" Since the output was "0.51..." this means that there exists two points which are that distance apart?

Comment: @Samuel I made a transcription error in my post: I left out `N`.  With that in place it should work.  `N` converts to numeric.  `Subsets[x, {2}]` gets all pairs of elements from `x`.  `EuclideanDistance` determines the distance between two vectors; it is "`Apply`'ed at level one" with the operator `@@@` which means that each pair of vertices is fed to the function in turn.  Finally `Min` is used to find the minimum value.  Documentation for each element can be found by highlighting it and pressing F1 in the Notebook.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I have solved that question now thanks to your answer!

Answer (score 5):

The figure I generated from the code in my answer ended up in a paper I wrote: arxiv.org/abs/1210.5756 if anyone is interested!

Thanks to the help of J.M. I was able to solve all of my problems relating to this question.
I first used the following code:

```
pts = FullSimplify[
    TrigExpand[(#1 Append[Sin[#2] Through[{Cos, Sin}[#3]], 
        Cos[#2]])]] & @@@ {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, Pi/3, 0}, {1, 
    Pi/3, ArcCos[1/3]}, {1, Pi/3, 2 ArcCos[1/3]}, {1, Pi/3, 
    3 ArcCos[1/3]}, {1, Pi/3, 
    4 ArcCos[1/3]}, {1, (2 Pi)/3, (ArcCos[1/3])/2}, {1, (2 Pi)/
     3, (3 ArcCos[1/3])/2}, {1, (2 Pi)/3, (5 ArcCos[1/3])/
     2}, {1, (2 Pi)/3, (7 ArcCos[1/3])/2}, {1, (2 Pi)/
     3, (9 ArcCos[1/3])/2}, {1, Pi, 0}}
```

Given the output of this, I was able to create a list $v$ of my vertices in Cartesian coordinates as,

```
 v = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/(2 Sqrt[3]), Sqrt[
   2/3], 1/2}, {-(7/(6 Sqrt[3])), (2 Sqrt[2/3])/3, 1/
   2}, {-(23/(18 Sqrt[3])), -((5 Sqrt[2/3])/9), 1/2}, {17/(
   54 Sqrt[3]), -((28 Sqrt[2/3])/27), 1/2}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/
   2, -(1/2)}, {-(1/(3 Sqrt[2])), 5/6, -(1/2)}, {-(11/(9 Sqrt[2])), 1/
   18, -(1/2)}, {-(13/(27 Sqrt[2])), -(43/54), -(1/2)}, {73/(
   81 Sqrt[2]), -(95/162), -(1/2)}, {0, 0, -1}}
```

By observing the following labelled vertices in J.M.'s answer and comparing it to my constructed model out of D&D dice I was able to come up with the following faces as a list.

```
i = {{1, 2, 7}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 8}, {4, 5, 2}, {2, 5, 6}, {2, 6, 
   7}, {1, 2, 3}, {7, 11, 12}, {6, 11, 7}, {8, 9, 4}, {13, 9, 8}, {13,
    10, 9}, {13, 11, 10}, {13, 12, 11}, {13, 1, 8}, {12, 1, 13}, {11, 
   1, 10}, {10, 9, 1}, {9, 1, 4}, {7, 1, 12}, {6, 1, 11}, {5, 4, 
   1}, {3, 1, 8}, {5, 6, 1}}
```

From this, I was able to use the Graphics3D and GraphicsComplex commands to generate the following figure by

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.95], Yellow, GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[i]], 
  MapIndexed[Style[Text[First[#2], #1, {-1, -1}], Red, 18] &, pts]}]
```

[image: Figure]

Thank you J.M.

Comment: Nicely done. :)