# Generating a non-convex polyhedron from polygons and normals

Tags: list-manipulation, mesh, computational-geometry, polyhedra, topology

I am working on developing "directional offset" module, which requires pretty tricky mesh generation: offset values vary in different directions.

Suppose I have list of points and polygons, from which I can make a meshregion and find normals.

How do I find the non-convex polyhedron from that?

Code by @whuber from this very helpful article [Generating convex polyhedron from face planes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14582/generating-convex-polyhedron-from-face-planes) generages perfect convex polyhedrons from my data.

Sometimes, several faces intersect at a vertex, but end up intersecting at a segment, which requires generatig new faces/polygons/verticies etc, and it does it. However, it cuts off all the concavities.

Here's what I need algo to do:

[image]

Here's what I get now:

[image]

In the second helpful article I've found [Generating a non-convex polyhedron from a list of vertex coordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/generating-a-non-convex-polyhedron-from-a-list-of-vertex-coordinates?rq=1) @J. M.'s slightly less busy shows a way to generate non-convex polygedron, but it needs a patch list as input to do what I need. This is not obvious for me, as new points and edges are generated during offset.

How do I get the most from both?

Here's the sample code I have:

```
(*Input Information*)

coords = {{5, -5, 0}, {0, 0, 20}, {0, -4.5, 2}, {-5, -5, 0}, {-5, 5, 0}, {0, 4.5, 2}, {5, 5, 0}};

cells = {Polygon[{1, 2, 3}], Polygon[{3, 2, 4}], Polygon[{5, 2, 6}], Polygon[{6, 2, 7}], Polygon[{2, 5, 4}], Polygon[{2, 1, 7}], Polygon[{5, 6, 4}], Polygon[{4, 6, 3}], Polygon[{6, 7, 3}], Polygon[{3, 7, 1}]};


(*Find Normals& Extract Face Points*)
inputmesh = MeshRegion[coords, cells, MeshCellStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];
allnormals = Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[inputmesh, 2];
allfacepts = coords[[#1 & @@@ (# & @@@ cells)]];

(*Find Duplicate Positions With Set Precision*)
positionDuplicates[list_] := GatherBy[Range@Length[list], Round[list[[#]], 1*^-3] &];

(*Get Rid Of Duplicationg Triangles And Generate Normals& Points List For Pylyhderon Generator*)
normals = allnormals[[#1 & @@@ positionDuplicates[allnormals]]];
pts = allfacepts[[#1 & @@@ positionDuplicates[allnormals]]];

(*Eliptical Offset Parameters*)
xyOffdirection = -1;(*'1' for thickening;'-1' thinning*)
rA = 2; rB = 1; Ang = 0/180*Pi;(*ellipse parameters*)

(*Calculate XY Offset Value From Dicection*)
xyOffv[x_, y_] := ((Cos[Ang - ArcTan[x, y]]*rA)^2 + (Sin[Ang - ArcTan[x, y]]*rB)^2)^0.5;

(*Calculate XY Offset Value From Normal*)
xyNormFunk[normals_] := {#1, #2, 0}* If[(#1^2 + #2^2) == 0, 0,xyOffv[#1, #2]/(#1^2 + #2^2)^0.5] & @@@ {normals};

(*Offset Points*)
offsettedpts = Table[pts[[i]] + xyOffdirection*Flatten[xyNormFunk[normals[[i]]], 1], {i, normals // Length}];

(*Convex Polyhedron Generator*)
polyhedron[normals_, pts_] := Module[{planes, nodes, vertices, incidence, adjacency, faceNodes, faceGraphs, orderings, faces, result}, planes = Union[MapThread[Append[-#1, #1 . #2] &, {normals, pts}]];
nodes = Union[Append[#, 1] & /@Quiet[Cases[ LinearSolve[Most /@ #, -Last /@ #] &/@Subsets[planes, {3}], _List]]];
vertices = DeleteDuplicates[Select[nodes, Chop[Min[planes . #]] >= 0 &],Chop[Norm[#1 - #2]] == 0 &];
incidence = SparseArray[ Outer[Boole[Chop[#1 . #2] == 0] &, vertices, planes, 1]];
adjacency = Map[Boole[# >= 2] &, incidence . incidence\[Transpose], {2}];
faceNodes = Flatten[Position[# // Normal, 1]] & /@ (incidence\[Transpose]);
faceGraphs = (SimpleGraph[AdjacencyGraph[adjacency[[#, #]]]] & /@faceNodes);
orderings = First /@ First[FindEulerianCycle[#]] & /@ faceGraphs;
faces = MapThread[Part, {faceNodes, orderings}];
result["vertices"] = Most /@ vertices; result["faces"] = faces;
result];

(*Generate Polyhedron*)
p = polyhedron[normals, offsettedpts];
vertices = p["vertices"];
faces = p["faces"];
v = Length[vertices];
polyGraphics = Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[ vertices, {Opacity[0.5], Polygon[faces], PointSize[0.015], Red,Opacity[1], Point[Range[v]]}]}];

(*Output*)
Show[inputmesh, polyGraphics, Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: What is the result about `ConcaveHullMesh[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1/3, 
    1/3}, {1, 2/3, 1/3}, {1, 1/3, 2/3}, {1, 2/3, 2/3}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 
    1, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}]` ?

Comment: You got me. It does not work in your case :)

Comment: You set `offset = -1`,but all of the two results does not have the same offset according to the normal.

Comment: You can test your code by setting `coords = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1/3, 2/
    3}, {1, 2/3, 2/3}, {1, 2/3, 1/3}, {1, 1/3, 1/3}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 0,
     0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1}};
cells = {Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4}], Polygon[{3, 2, 5, 6}], 
   Polygon[{4, 3, 6, 7}], Polygon[{2, 1, 8, 5}], 
   Polygon[{1, 4, 7, 8}], Polygon[{9, 10, 11, 12}], 
   Polygon[{9, 12, 6, 5}], Polygon[{12, 11, 7, 6}], 
   Polygon[{10, 9, 5, 8}], Polygon[{11, 10, 8, 7}]};` and set  `xyOffdirection` by small number for example `-.1`.

Comment: @cvgmt, this way it does not work either. Btw, I noticed, in your first example, normals were not always pointing outside.

Answer (score 4):

- `SignedRegionDistance`.

```
mesh = BoundaryMeshRegion[coords, cells, 
   MeshCellStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];
dist=SignedRegionDistance@mesh;
plot = ContourPlot3D[dist@{x, y, z} == -1, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh, 
  RegionBoundaryStyle -> None];
Show[mesh, plot]
```

[image]

- `ScalingTransform`

For this simple case it seems work.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ScalingTransform[t*{1, 1, 1}, RegionCentroid@mesh]@mesh, 
  mesh], {{t, .71}, 0.01, 1}]
```

[image]

- The main difficult is that we can not use `RegionIntersection` and `HalfSpace` to get such region.

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[#, PlotRange -> 20] & /@ 
   MapThread[
    HalfSpace, {allnormals, 
     RegionCentroid@*Polygon /@ (coords[[#]] & /@ cells[[;; , 1]]) - 
      1.*allnormals}] // RegionIntersection // Region
Show[mesh, %]
```

[image]

- Test another cases.

```
Clear[reg, reg1, reg2, dist, plot];
reg1 = 
 ConvexHullMesh[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1/3, 
    1/3}, {1, 2/3, 1/3}, {1, 1/3, 2/3}, {1, 2/3, 2/3}}];
reg2 = ConvexHullMesh[{{1, 1/3, 1/3}, {1, 2/3, 1/3}, {1, 1/3, 
     2/3}, {1, 2/3, 2/3}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}];
reg = RegionUnion[reg1, reg2];
dist = SignedRegionDistance@reg;
plot = ContourPlot3D[dist@{x, y, z} == -.1, {x, y, z} ∈ reg, 
   RegionBoundaryStyle -> None];
Show[Region[Style[reg, Opacity[.2]]], plot]
```

Or

```
coords = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1/3, 2/
    3}, {1, 2/3, 2/3}, {1, 2/3, 1/3}, {1, 1/3, 1/3}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 0,
     0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1}};
cells = {Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4}], Polygon[{3, 2, 5, 6}], 
   Polygon[{4, 3, 6, 7}], Polygon[{2, 1, 8, 5}], 
   Polygon[{1, 4, 7, 8}], Polygon[{9, 10, 11, 12}], 
   Polygon[{9, 12, 6, 5}], Polygon[{12, 11, 7, 6}], 
   Polygon[{10, 9, 5, 8}], Polygon[{11, 10, 8, 7}]};
mesh = BoundaryMeshRegion[coords, cells, 
   MeshCellStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];
dist = SignedRegionDistance@mesh;
plot = ContourPlot3D[dist@{x, y, z} == -.1, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh,
    RegionBoundaryStyle -> None];
Show[mesh, plot]
```

[image]

- And the result as below is not correct.

```
coords = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1/3, 
    2/3}, {1, 2/3, 2/3}, {1, 2/3, 1/3}, {1, 1/3, 1/3}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 
    0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1}};
cells = {Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4}], Polygon[{3, 2, 5, 6}], 
   Polygon[{4, 3, 6, 7}], Polygon[{2, 1, 8, 5}], 
   Polygon[{1, 4, 7, 8}], Polygon[{9, 10, 11, 12}], 
   Polygon[{9, 12, 6, 5}], Polygon[{12, 11, 7, 6}], 
   Polygon[{10, 9, 5, 8}], Polygon[{11, 10, 8, 7}]};
mesh = BoundaryMeshRegion[coords, cells, 
   MeshCellStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];

allnormals = Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[mesh, 2]; 
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[#, PlotRange -> 20] & /@ 
   MapThread[
    HalfSpace, {allnormals, 
     RegionCentroid@*
        Polygon /@ (coords[[#]] & /@ cells[[;; , 1]]) - .1*
       allnormals}] // RegionIntersection // Region;
Show[mesh, %]
```

[image]